# Laptop takes 1-2min for network connection to start on wakeup, even when wired

Tags: laptop, network-adapter, wake-up, delay

The first thing I did after purchasing an HP Pavilion dv6, was replacing the HD with an SSD and installing Windows 7 Home Premium on it (I'm not sure if the issue occurred with the original drive).

The laptop has been good so far, with one annoying fault. When it wakes up from sleep, the network takes 1-2 minutes to become active. Often while refreshing a webpage waiting for it to work, it'll work for a second and then drop out again, until eventually it works solid. During this process the system tray icon displays the exclamation mark showing no internet access.

It's sitting on a desk, hard-wired into my network, with a static IP and DNS. The modem itself is working fine because other devices have full connectivity while this is happening.

Device manager shows the network adapter as a Realtek PICe GBE Family Controller and claims the drivers are up-to-date (driver version 7.41.216.2011)

Ideas for troubleshooting?

Comment: I guess it's a Realtek driver bug. I have been trying to find a solution for this problem for months... It seems some non-driver component must be started for the NIC to work.

Comment: Try disabling any and all network management applications (such as those that come with wireless cards). Also try disabling the card from control panel before going to sleep. Try changing the ACPI sleep state in BIOS and perhaps reinstalling the ACPI drivers and service.

Comment: & try disabling network drivers that are not being used.